# Unity game - Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

for my game I created a prefab creating  a shop panel with a working button, text, etc in my tower defense game. I have a public bool of if the player has a tower, called hasTower as seen below.

```
public class CellScr : MonoBehaviour {

public bool isGround, hasTower = false;
```

Later in the script, I have a code that if hasTower = true, that the system would find the game object from the prefab and destroy is (CloseShop).

```
    public void BuildTower(Tower tower) // From another script
{
    GameObject tmpTower = Instantiate (TowerPref);
    tmpTower.transform.SetParent (transform, false);
    tmpTower.transform.position = transform.position;
    tmpTower.GetComponent<TowerScr>().selfType = (TowerType)tower.type;

    hasTower = true;
    FindObjectOfType<ShopScr> ().CloseShop;
}
```

In Shop Script (a different script), I have the public method of CloseShop:

```
public void CloseShop()

{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

which closes the window of the shop in my game.

There is another script Tower Script, the bool determines if the player has a tower or not. In the ShopScr, there is also an option to build a tower based on your amount of gold. Including all these scripts will make the question too long, and those do not have the errors in them, as they work fine.

The problem here is that the public bool doesn't work, and gives my the error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

How can I make the game recognize the method of CloseShop?

Sorry this may be a stupid question, but I just started programming recently, especially with Unity.

Comment: Where *exactly* did you put those lines? They must be inside a method

Comment: Are the `()` in the wrong place?  FindObjectOfType<ShopScr> ().CloseShop;

Comment: Anyone not closing this question as a typo is doing the wrong thing...

Comment: This error has nothing to do with starting in Unity, when you call a method in `c#`, you should always have parenthesis, even if there are no arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CloseShop` is a method, you're missing parenthesis:

```
FindObjectOfType<ShopScr>().CloseShop();
```

Answer (score 2):

**CloseShop** is a method so you should have a trailing pair of brackets after it.

```
FindObjectOfType<ShopScr>().CloseShop();
```

Comment: Except that `()` are called parenthesis - brackets are `[]`

Comment: In UK English `()` are called both "brackets" or "parentheses".  `[]` are "square brackets".  Technically braces, `{}`, are also called "brackets", but anyone doing that needs a slap :).

Comment: @CodeGorilla Haha thanks for clarifications ! :) I'd need to double check for UK/US English every time. And everybody should adopt a standard, but it's not for tomorrow